# Write one function with certain traits

Tags: functions

I have to write function which:

- R as domain
- is monotonous on all its domain
- f'(-1)=f'(1)=0  [it is first derivation]

I cannot think of that one. :) Can you please help me? thx a lot

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$?

Comment: I think you probably mean "monotonic" or "monotone" rather than "monotonous".

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(x)=\pi x+\sin(\pi x)$? Can you check that all those conditions hold for this function?

Comment: It should be as follows: every next functional value must be "<" or ">" than previous on all its domain

Comment: does something like this exist?